# With using OptionSetTypes, how would and assignment(&=) or or assignment (|=) be used?

Tags: objective-c, swift, bitwise-operators

I am creating a class that utilizes swift's optionsettype protocol that I am converting from objective C enum. I see how they can be helpful with providing information on the state of an action or object, like the direction of a joystick or scrolling. I am having trouble wrapping my head around how certain bitwise operators would be converted to be more swiftie.

From the OptionSetType protocol document:

```
struct PackagingOptions : OptionSetType {
    let rawValue: Int
    init(rawValue: Int) { self.rawValue = rawValue }

    static let Box = PackagingOptions(rawValue: 1)
    static let Carton = PackagingOptions(rawValue: 2)
    static let Bag = PackagingOptions(rawValue: 4)
    static let Satchel = PackagingOptions(rawValue: 8)
    static let BoxOrBag: PackagingOptions = [Box, Bag]
    static let BoxOrCartonOrBag: PackagingOptions = [Box, Carton, Bag]
}

var packagingOptions: PackingOptions = .Box

if packingOptions == .Box {
    packingOptions |= .Satchel
}
```

Would it be translated to the following instead?

packaingOptions = [PackagingOptions, .Satchel]

I believe that has the same effect as bitwise or assignment. How would and assignment work in the above scenario?

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the point of Swift's Option Set type. The idea is that you do *not* use bitwise "and" or "or". You can, but you don't, because they are error prone and confusing. Instead, you use *set* operations.

```
var packagingOptions: PackagingOptions = [.Box] // it's a _set_
if somethingOrOther {
    packagingOptions.insert(.Satchel) // it's a _set_
}
```

Similarly, yes, you *can* say

```
var packagingOptions: PackagingOptions = [.Box, .Satchel] // it's a _set_
```

And, just the other way around, you can check for a particular bit by checking the contents of the set:

```
if packagingOptions.contains(.Box) ... // it's a _set_
```

You can't do *any* of that in Objective-C. It is this set-like behavior that gives an Option Set its worth.

Comment: For a full discussion, see my online book: http://www.apeth.com/swiftBook/ch04.html#SECoptionsSets